# Python - ANSI highlight text printing out weird character instead of highlighting

Tags: python, unicode, ansi-escape

I'm kind of a beginner in Python, and I wanted to highlight some text printed out such as warning, bold whatsoever, using ANSI values.

I found this question ([Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)) in Stack Overflow and I kind of used my own approach:

```
import sys

def hilite(status, string = ''):
    if sys.stdout.isatty():
                    # Header   # Ok Blue    #Ok Green   # Warning   # Fail      # Bold   # Underline
        attr = ['\033[95m', '\033[94m', '\033[92m', '\033[93m', '\033[91m', '\033[1m', '\033[4m']
        ENDC = '\033[0m'
        print(attr[status]+ string +ENDC)
    else:
        print(string)

# header
hilite(0, '\t\t\t\tMy Python program')
```

**Output:**

```
←[95m                   My Python program←[0m
```

I tried the original approach but same results. I'm using Windows.

Comment: You're using Windows. Using ANSI escape sequences won't work using the default MS Windows console.

Comment: oh, so is there any way to make it supported or another way of displaying with color?

Comment: I'm not a windows specialist so I leave the answer to others. However I strongly suggest using an appropriate existing module like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: OK, thanks man. I'll give it a try

Comment: Even on Unix/Linux is this code working only on certain types of terminal. Even if it is the most common one, you should never hardcode the escape sequences. See the curses library. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: colorama and termcolor are working good

Answer (score 1):

I am a beginner too but I have experimented with ANSI and did a project to change the text color of "Dead Words" inside of a string. I used the question posted to solve my code problem. I removed the if statements on this sample so you could run it. Do you need the statements? What exactly are you using this for? This code should work for your string. But if you need the if statements make sure the if statement can be true or will let the code redirect it to print the colored versions. The only problem was the if statement directing you to just print the normal string.

```
def highlight(status, string = ''):
   # Header   # Ok Blue    #Ok Green   # Warning   # Fail      # Bold   
   #Underline
   attr = ['\033[95m', '\033[94m', '\033[92m', '\033[93m', '\033[91m', 
   '\033[1m', '\033[4m']
   ENDC = '\033[0m'
   print(attr[status]+ string +ENDC)

   # header
highlight(0, '\t\t\t\tMy Python program')
```